# Counting function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I need to have multiple counters so I created a function, the problem is that I can't store the value in the variable outside the function. I thought this would be easy but I couldn't find anything online.

```
myCounter = 2;
function count(counter) {
   counter++;;
}
count(myCounter);
```

I would get the value in myCounter to update every time I call the function, thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: "*I need to have multiple counters so I created a function*" - you wrote a function that increments a count, not a function that creates a counter. There still is only one counter. Use a closure if you want multiple ones. Also please show us the code on how you would want to *use* multiple distinct counters.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments and sorry if the question wasn't clear, I used an object to save all counts so I could use the index as parameter

Comment: @hev1 inside the object I store more than one count so I have to use the object key as the function parameter

Comment: Would you mind providing an example object?

Comment: `const counters = {wt: 1, se: 2};

function count(counterKey) {
    counters[counterKey]++;
}
count('wt');
count('se');`

Comment: @Bort_Bot Is that the solution you were looking for or do you still have questions about this code?

Comment: @Bergi That's the solution thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure function that returns an object with a getter so you can initialize as many individual instances as you need

```js
function counter() {
  let _count = 0;
  return {
    get count() {
      return ++_count;
    }
  }
}


let ct1 = new counter();
console.log('ct1', ct1.count, ct1.count)


let ct2 = new counter();
console.log('ct2', ct2.count, ct2.count, ct2.count)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```js
var myCounter = 2;
var myCounter2 = 3;

function count(counter) {
  return ++counter;
}
myCounter = count(myCounter);
myCounter2 = count(myCounter2);
console.log('myCounter: ' + myCounter);
console.log('myCounter2: ' + myCounter2);
```

Comment: How is this scalable to multiple counters?

Comment: But OP clearly stated they can't use multiple variables outside of the function